# error in '[.dt_df'(Final, i, index): object not found

Tags: r, function

I am running an r function (below) to assign `ndvi` values (exposure) from a dataframe (`df2`) to persons aged 10 years in `df1`. In both dataframes, I have a key variable which is their residential address labeled `index` in `df1` and `index10` in `df2`.

```
addNDVI = function(Final,NDVI,Names){
  for(i in 1:nrow(Final)){
    #i = 1001
    Cols = paste(c("meanNDVI","sdNDVI"),Final[i,Year10],sep="")
    Val = NDVI[Final[i,index10] == NDVI[,index],Cols, with = F]
    if(nrow(Val) > 0) Final[i, Names[1:2] := Val, with =F]
    if(i %in% seq(0,nrow(Final),by = 10000)) print(i)
    } 
  return(Final)
}
```

When I run

`df1 = addNDVI(df1,df2,c("NDVImean7","NDVIsd7"))`

I get the error message

> `error in [.dt_df'(Final, i, index): object index not found`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correct it?

Thank you.

NB: I am very new to R started using just three months ago

Comment: In the function `index` object was not creatd or it is passed as an argument

Comment: Is this a `data.table`? If it's (just) a `data.frame`, then you cannot subset a column named `"index"` with unquoted names such as `NDVI[,index]`.

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for the suggestion. my ndvi dataset was in dataframe format. the function worked after converting it to data.table :)